# Get all reviews and ratting from gplus

Tags: google-plus

I have to get list of comment and rating of my  goolge-plus page in json format form this url (test url)

https://plus.google.com/b/116355901745826833455/116355901745826833455/posts

I try in developer section of google-plus page. but i dont get appropriate method to find this. please any body can told me in which section of google developer i found this method. this is the first time i have to integrate any google api.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/comments/list will try tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your Google+ Page, you can make a call to activities.list using the Google+ Page ID to see all of the public posts that the Page has made, including +1s and comments and reshares on those posts. The documentation explains it well and also has an [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list) which you can try for yourself.

For additional information on a particular post, you can try [comments.list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/comments/list)--as you mentioned--or [activities.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/get).

For the number of +1s for the Google+ Page specifically, you can try a [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) call using the Page ID.

Comment: thanks i got rating but still not got reviews of google plus page

Answer (score 1):

The Google+ API does provide you with some information you ask for as Joanna states, but I believe what you really are looking for is the [Place details within the Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details), which provides details about businesses, such as reviews. That API will return ratings and reviews. If you also needed +1s then you'd need to use both APIs.