# APIs for posting reviews on Facebook and Google+ business pages

Tags: facebook, api, post, google-plus, review

Is there a way to get as well as post reviews from a website to Google + business page and Facebook business page?

What i mean is that if i have ratings and reviews present on my website, are there any APIs from Google+ or/and Facebook that allow me to post those reviews on the business pages.

we also have have email ids of customers attached to these reviews if its required.

Answer (score 2):

The Google+ API is a *read-only* API, meaning that there is no way to post a review through the traditional Google+ API. However, you may be able to post to a Google+ Page that you own if you gain access to the Google+ Pages API. This is a closed API, though, so you will need to [apply](https://developers.google.com/+/api/pages-signup).

For information on how to get current reviews, see [this existing StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306157/get-all-reviews-and-ratting-from-gplus).

Comment: Is it possible through the google-maps-api ? I didn't found anything